# Could medieval people build an airtight spaceship or space ark using their common resources?

Tags: space, aliens, medieval, natural-resources, ships

This is set on a fictional alien world with medieval people. However, this world has alien livestock that are capable of flying into outer space and traveling to other worlds. These medieval-age people figured out how to use the animals to tow their ships from planet to planet, all with no technology. Would they be able to create a ship or ark that can withstand the elements of outer space using common materials? They would have protection against radiation and have their own source of water and heat and air and water using fictional means. However they would need to build their ships using common resources such as oil, tar, wood, etc. Is it possible to build a ship or ark out of wood and other common materials that won't implode in space? They would also have their own type of epoxy sealant that will make their ships absolutely airtight, which would also protect them and their ships from radiation, etc.

Comment: Short answer: No / Slightly more nuanced answer: Given a short enough travel time between planets they could perhaps do an adequate job to hold in sufficient atmosphere for long enough for them to travel from planet A to planet B, the radiation isn't a problem they'll even be aware of so they won't do anything about it though (assuming these flying beasts have adequate lifting & propulsive power) it would be easy for even their tech to solve as all it needs is adequate shielding so it's just an issue of mass & weight.

Comment: If the question assumes an endless ability to generate energy and matter out of nothing (food, water, air, heat) anything is possible. This does, however, badly violate physics and causality. Build a bubble out of your perfect epoxy and skip the hull entirely. Your issue would be the gasses exploding, not imploding. How long are the voyages the ships need to make? What sort of sheer and G-forces do they need to endure?

Comment: Is vacuum and radiation protection the only requirement? How about life support?

Comment: The voyages would take maybe a few hours to weeks. As this is a fictional setting, it is set in a solar system that shares over 300 planets and one sun where the wildlife evolved to migrate from planet to planet. When the animals reach space, they're capable of reaching near-lightspeed to "jump" from planet to planet. They have naturally occurring fictional crystal-stones that somehow use the elements, some create air, others create water, others heat, others anti-gravity, others create light, and so on, which they use in their ship/arks. Their superstrong epoxy should help w/ sheer & g-force?

Comment: I'm not sure what the actual question is. You've stated magic crystals (best to edit details like that into the question as comments get deleted), and you've talked about implosion of the capsule - which it wouldn't, a pressurized capsule would explode in a vacuum (if at all). Can you [edit] to clear-up the misunderstandings and clarify what it is you're actually asking. Whilst you're at it, take our [tour] and refer to the [help] about how we work, welcome to worldbuilding.

Comment: The question is, they need to build ships that can withstand outer space. Their resources for water, air, heat and light is what they have to survive inside their ships and has nothing to do with building ships themselves. But is it possible build a ship or ark out of wood and common materials to survive traveling the void of outer space itself?

Comment: Do you want to edit the question with all the details in the comments and take the tour then?

Comment: I don't know why the question needs to be edited when the question is simple. Can a ship be constructed out of wood and common materials that would maintain structural integrity and not leak air? That's it. It has nothing to do with their resources for air, water and heat.

Comment: Turtledove has a story (*The Road Less Traveled*) where most civilizations quickly discover the principles of anti-gravity and achieve spaceflight at a very low level of technology. The only other requisite seems to be building airtight metal modules. One civilization hadn't even entered the iron age, they built theirs from bronze. The tradeoff is that once you discover this, the scientific principle seems like bullshit, and so you stagnate and never develop anything else. Earth is invaded by an army of aliens wielding flintlock rifles, much to their sorrow.

Comment: @JR710er It's a binary question - yes/no. As such it's not a good fit for our format, a question asking "how....?" would get more interesting and useful answers.

Comment: Thank you but i'm not asking for suggestions or ideas on how it could be done. I'm asking if it's possible or plausible to construct a ship or ark out of wood and common materials to withstand space travel. In effect, a binary question.

Comment: What about using the hides of the beasts that migrate?

Comment: worth noting a pressurized ship will not implode, it will explode in a vacuum. Also what you you mean by having a source of air, does it maintain normal pressure, does it remove Co2 and add oxygen, if you can magically make air fast it does not need ot be airtight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If airtightness is the only requirement, then yes, medieval people could create such vessels**

By middle ages, creating watertight ship hulls was a very common task. Yes, ships leaked, but that could be successfully mitigated.

Also, diving bells were known since antiquity, and fully isolated "dry" bell is not very different from a spaceship. 1 atm pressure difference could be easily handled by wood and metal construction.

Dealing with the coldness of space is more tricky, because iron will become brittle, and any wet insulation will become dry, but if medieval NASA can get enough tries, they can find out what works and what not.

Radiation hazard can be mitigated by building thicker hulls. This is something that the builders absolutely can do, but they must know it from somewhere, or learn the hard way.

Excessive G forces, atmospheric shocks, high temperatures and life support would probably be too much to handle for medieval technology, but that seems to be outside of scope of this question.

Comment: Vacuum is not cold. On the contrary, vacuum is an excellent thermal insulator. I would be very much more afraid of being cooked in a medieval spacecraft than of being frozen. (And in real history, [Otto von Guericke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otto_von_Guericke#Air_pressure_and_the_vacuum)'s famous "Magdeburg hemispheres" experiment demonstratring atmospheric pressure happened in 1657. Yes, it's 200 years after the end of the Middle Ages but it is still proof that airtight vessels able to withstand 1 atmosphere of pressure *could* be made by Renaissance-level technology.)

Comment: @AlexP vacuum is not cold, so as it not an insulator - the sun is the proof. It looks like insulator because at low temperatures black body radiation flow isn't that high. If I remember rigth it about 450W/m2 for 300K. And sure with star next to them cooking may be a real problem.

Comment: @MolbOrg: An excellent thermal insulator is not a perfect thermal insulator; and of course we are speaking about temperatures where humans don't get vaporized. (On the other hand, solar irradiance around Earth is about 1360 W/m², but of course those are cross-sectional square meters.)

Comment: @AlexP good point about the thermal balance, although for the _internal_ comfort I assumed this is an out of scope problem. For the conditions on the outer surface of the spaceship (which should be in scope) the heat on the sunny side should not be as bad as to cause any issues to wood or metal, however, the cold in the shade can be an issue.

Comment: Ships are not very water tight, and wood will get much less watertight when subjected to vacuum. more importantly to survive weeks or months you need a gigantic ship to have enough air. a person needs a bout a shipping crate of air for each day.

Comment: Idk, what I think the answer can benefit from, it skip that termal and other stuff completly, but add some numbers for a construction, maybe wooden one or material of choice, and look and quantify it in some way. Making things airtight, probably not a problem, tar and stuff,  but can they make construction itself. Scale up that Magdeburg thing to a size of a ship of that era and see what it is as a construction. And then if there is energy left think about how it behaves, cold hot air aspects of it. CaO can be used to bind CO2, so no CO2 poisoning problem.

Comment: @John freshly tarred boats are quite watertight. After a while ship's seams are loosening, so it's a good question for how long medieval spaceship can stay airtight in space.

Comment: @Alexander watertight is different than airtight under pressure, a pumpkin is watertight.

Comment: @MolbOrg for more specific design plans we need more specific requirements.

Comment: @John pumpkin shell is less strong than wood or metal. My point is that 1 atmosphere is not that much.

Comment: @Alexander for a nay-answer, yes, probbly it needs specific requirements, but for a yes one it needs just one case to show it possible at least in a such way(and more freedom the better). And second point is when such work is done then it makes some sens to investigate it a bit further to see what else it can and I suspect that for a construction they can make - coldness, Radiation, probbly are not important thing and not worth mentionin, but other things my become worthy of mention. I mean have no model at all is in the way of good yes anwer. But sure, it all up to you - do or don't.

Comment: Diving bells are fundamentally different from a space ship, because in a diving bell the inner pressure is exactly balanced by the outer pressure. In a space ship, you have a gas at a pressure of 1 bar inside, and vacuum at 0 bar outside; that's a force of 10 tons per square meter trying to disassemble your ship.

Comment: @AlexP that's for the "wet" diving bells; 10 tons per square meter is not that bad, medieval tech can handle that.

Comment: @Alexander not on the scale need, sure they can make fridge sized or smaller airtight pressure vessel, buy you need something gigantic, something that can keep a human alive for weeks. Even something the size of the Heidelberg tun will be hard pressed to keep a human alive for a day.

Comment: @John This is not how I understand the question. "keep a human alive for weeks" is not in the scope here. If we do need to factor in life support, then of course the problem gets much more complicated.

Comment: Absolutely not. They can't compress the air they'd need to breathe, they don't have the precision tooling needed to fabricate joints that can hold up 15 psi in a vacuum, and they have no material that can take the radiation sleeting from the sun, and worse, they don't have clocks precise enough to navigate with. How will they survive a fall from interplantetary space through what they think is a breathable atmosphere, in an organic ship? How does it even survive acceleration to escape velocity? Epoxy? Rivets? How do they solve the ballistics of such trips? What about bone loss from low G?

Comment: @Alexander in the comments the OP clarifies the trips can last from hours to weeks.

Comment: @John So? "have their own source of water and heat and air and water using **fictional means**" - I read it as everything related to life support and comfort is provided by magic.

Comment: @Alexander Good catch we need clarification on that.

Comment: I think you can ignore the G-forces. I guess it's fair to assume that the g-forces the animals can withstand should be in the same order as those the humans can. And since the animals obviously survive their space trips, the humans should, too.
Don't ask me how, though. But if it was otherwise, the animals could not have evolved to do it, because of going splat prevents breeding.

Answer (score 4):

No.

they can't make a airtight container big enough for weeks of travel, especially not one that can withstand vacuum. Even a day of travel is probably impossible. You need a shipping container worth of air per person per day. Since it needs to have doors it gets even less likely they can make it airtight.

The only technology they had for making airtight containers either relied on glass, or barrels, which have a scaling limit.  if the travel times was an hour or few they could maybe manage with large single use barrels, assuming they someone at the other end to let them out. But even then it is iffy, wooden barrels can't withstand much internal pressure.  Even the materials themselves have problems. Wood, tar, pitch, glue, all these materials outgas in a vacuum, meaning they won't work for a seal in vacuum, natural material don't make great vacuum seals. if this is actually space, then uneven heating by the sun will cause even more deformation which is destructive ot seals.

**Material problems**

large barrels and ships are made in very similar ways at least in terms of making them watertight, tight fitting planks with either with nothing (rare) or a caulking (common) sealing joints. Usually cordage soaked in pitch or tar. All of which seriously outgas under vacuum, so they will break down or  fail almost instantly when subjected to vacuum. Sealing things against vacuum is hard without modern materials because all traditional glues and sealers contain volatiles the boil off at vacuum pressures which destroys the material. If you want to get an idea of what happens put a marshmallow in a microwave. Even the water in the wood will boil off deteriorating any seals in contact with it and can even damage the wood itself.

**Mechanical problems**

Barrels work much better for our purposes because they are reinforced on the outside relying on compression to seal them so they can withstand some pressurization, but they still suffer the outgassing problem and the internal pressure they can withstand is still low, the end caps can't be braced like the sides so this is where leaks tend to start. Ships are pegged/bolted into place so will be far weaker to internal pressure, which makes sense they are designed to withstand great *external* pressure.

Comment: I made a comment under Alexander's answer, and in some sense it applies to this answer as well. Atm there is yes and no answer but both have no numbers, just some statements and yeah some ideas reasoning but there is no information which uses science to show or support any of those statemens. This time, I wanna be a baby girl(google traffic user) traveling in a train and looking in the windows to see the world, keeping calculator in its scabbard.

Comment: @MolbOrg there are no numbers to apply, this is about construction methods not tolerances. medieval societies only had a few ways to make airtight containers, only one of the scales and it can't hold much pressure. volume and Co2 concentration which would be the limiting factor with a large airtight container does not even get a chance to come into play,

Comment: Do you know how hulls of wooden ships were made? Meaning technology? It almost composite technology. Not sure since when, but was watching repair of 100 something year old yacht. So as old ships 200+  had suprisingly nice displacement. Barrels are not the only technology which was available to solve the problem. But sure it up to you will you investigate or improve the q. Quality of both answers atm is not very high, and that with relatively simple OP's q which is tangible engeneering and history. Is wb become way too relaxed on grazing those magic q's to the point not being able to walk?

Comment: @MolbOrg large barrels and ships are made in very similar ways at least in terms of making them watertight, tight fitting planks either with nothing (rare) or a caulking (common) usually cordage soaked in pitch or tar. all of which seriously outgas under vacuum. barrels work much better for our purposes because they are reinforced on the outside relying on compression to seal them. they can withstand some internal pressure, ships are pegged/bolted into place so will be even weaker to internal pressure.

Comment: @MolbOrg: The hull of a ship is stressed in compression. Water wants to come in under some pressure, you want to stop it. It is not hard to make a strong vessel able to resist outside pressure. Making a vessel able to conain inside pressure is a very different problem; atmospheric pressure is 1 kg / square centimeter, meaning 10 tons per square meter. That's an awful lot of force for a pre-modern container. (For example, the wind chests of a pipe organ held compressed air at about 0.007 atmospheres; yes, 7 **milli**bars.)

Comment: Okay, seems for the most time it was clinker and carvel builds, and Linen build was 19th century, and its more modern variations probbly weren't used. On the other hand warships had quite a thickness of the hull, also in 19th(?). Okay, not an expert on shipbuilding, and maybe just maybe remembered it wrong that warships had 0.5m thick hull or something. Frame for ships was used since 14th(?) which is probably sufficient difference from barels tech, at least those I know. Using sap/tar to seal stuff from inside was within their tech. // Okay, seems it requires some willingness to make it happen

Comment: @AlexP I had in mind tech similar to linen build(how planks are arranged), and other stuff. Ship hull is not an egg, it expirience many forces, and with double or triple diagonal planking it not much different from engineered wood and plywood tech. With frames and such I could imagine some potencial construction, but how medieval it would be is not clear. I think they could adress and figure things out(some solutions are just too straigth forward) if they had the neccessity and abiity to test/expirience the problems. But okay it all needs digging and then making answer, but not going to.

Comment: @MolbOrg I mentioned pitch and tar several times they outgas and release a lot, resin will do the same, as will all available glues, this is why sealing things in space is so hard, many materials are not chemically stable in a vacuum because they contain volatiles which boil off. even the wood itself will do this to an extent as the water and several other compounds boil out in vacuum.

Comment: The air supply issue means you'll have a large ship with a small crew.  That doesn't make it impossible unless the ship is too much for the propulsion.

Comment: @LorenPechtel the larger your make a structure out of wood and outgassing seals the greater the chance it will fail, there is an upper limit on how big you can build a wooden barrel or ship, they get weaker as the size increases and the chances of a seal failing also increases.

Comment: @John It's going to have to be metal, not wood.  Wood is going to be weakened by the outgassing.  It's one big, expensive ship but the question was whether it was possible, not whether it was affordable.